# Python linear mixed model predict

Tags: python, model, statsmodels

How I can use the predict method
after fitting a model (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/umich.box.com/shared/static/6tfc1e0q6jincsv5pgfa.ipynb)

With the simple dietox example I get an error.

```
data = pd.read_csv("dietox.csv")
model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula("Weight ~ Time", data, groups=data["Pig"])
result = model.fit()
print result.summary()
#this and other attempts doesn't work
result.predict(data.ix[1])
```

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ba818b886233> in <module>()
 ----> 1 result.predict(data.ix[1])

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.pyc in predict(self,      exog, transform, *args, **kwargs)
 747             exog = np.atleast_2d(exog)  # needed in count model shape[1]
 748 
--- > 749    return self.model.predict(self.params, exog, *args, **kwargs)
 750
 751

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.pyc in predict(self, params, exog, *args, **kwargs)
    175         This is a placeholder intended to be overwritten by individual models.
    176         """
--> 177         raise NotImplementedError
    178 
    179 

NotImplementedError:
```

Comment: What error? Please post a full traceback so the question is more informative without having to run the example.

Comment: I added the error message

Comment: Thanks, that's more informative. The `predict` method wasn't available in the 0.6 version. It is in statsmodels master only since July. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/2363   I haven't checked the example.

Comment: Ahh thanks didn't notice that.